# getComputedStyle в процентах

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток, форумчане. Не подскажет ли кто, как получить размеры элемента в том виде, как они записаны в css? А то getComputedStyle любит все переводить в пиксели.
Заранее спасибо.

**Добавлено**
Видимо, кроссбраузерного решения проблемы нет, поэтому придется действовать грубо и некрасиво. А жаль.
А вопрос еще не закрыт. ;)

Comment: Дык по этому и называется computed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если стиль задается внутри тега

```
<div id="w_div" style="width:10%"></div>
```

тогда заданные размеры можно получить через

```
document.getElementById('w_div').style.width
```

если в блоке `<style></style>` либо в подключаемом файле, могу только сказать что копать в направлении

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.width
```

Comment: Через styleSheets копаться можно, но можно и не докопаться. А можно и браузер подвесить, если делать это на ресайзе. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
var realCssSize = jQuery("#targetId").css("width")
```

так найдём ширину элемента, которая записана в CSS-стиле

Comment: В Webkit'е jQuery тоже возвращает пиксели. Проценты она возвращает только если задать их через jQuery или в inline-стилях.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть `currentStyle`?

Comment: поправьте если ошибаюсь но currentStyle для ie только и то до 9-й версии.

Comment: @FLK, не знаю, может быть, я всего лишь предположил.

Comment: Да, currentStyle работает только в ИЕ.